# Integrate CKEeditor with ACEeditor

Tags: ace-editor

Can any tell how to integrate CKEeditor with ACE editor as codesnippet.
Now I use CKEditor with highlight, but try to use with ACE ([https://ace.c9.io/#nav=abou](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)t)

Detailed explanation:

I use ACE as an editor for PLSQL, SQL, Javascript, ...

For documentation, I use CKE. But in some CKE documents, I need to include code (PlSql, Sql, JS, css).

I use a plugin in CKE to highlight syntax. That plugin is "codesnippet" and the syntax highligter is uses by default is "highlight".

What I try is to change the default syntax highligter in CKE to use ACE. I've seen it's possible, or perhaps it was possible [Integrate CKE and ACE](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), but that documentation is old and example doesn't exists.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You'd be better advised using a CKeditor plugin for this rather than trying to integrate ace. http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your needs "codesnippet", so taking a shot in the dark here.

I use CKEditor plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/pbckcode which has the ACE Editor for many projects.

You might read **more about the plugin** [here](http://pierrebaron.fr/pbckcode/) to see if it fits your needs. I have been very happy with it.